# React/Redux - Events between parent and childs for menu and items

Tags: reactjs, coffeescript, redux, cjsx

I'm trying to build a Menu, with MenuItem(s), from scratch. I'm using React 0.14 and Redux, with CoffeeScript (cjsx). *(I'm just getting started with all of those)*

I'm stuck because I don't know how to give the MenuItem(s) the reference to the callback function `onChildrenClick`. Because they are generated through `{this.props.children}` I don't know how I'm supposed to add a `props` there.

**Menu.cjsx**

```
React = require 'react'

class Menu extends React.Component

    @propTypes =
        children: React.PropTypes.array.isRequired

    render: ->
        <div className="ui pointing menu">
            {this.props.children} # I don't see how I can bind the "onChildrenClick" function to the child, because they're generated outside of this scope. Maybe by looping on "this.props.children"? I tried but it wasn't successful. 
        </div>

    onChildrenClick: (event) ->
        console.log event

module.exports = Menu
```

**MenuItem.cjsx**

```
React = require 'react'
classNames = require('classnames')

class MenuItem extends React.Component

    @propTypes =
        label: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired
        active: React.PropTypes.bool

    constructor: (props) ->
        super props

        @state =
            classes: classNames(
                'ui'
                'item'
                'active': this.props.active
            )

    render: ->
        <a className={@state.classes} onClick={@onClick}>
            { this.props.label }
        </a>

    onClick: =>
        console.log Object.assign @state.classes, {active: !@state.classes.active}
        @setState({classes: Object.assign @state.classes, {active: true}})
        console.log @state.classes # I need to notify the parent so it can notify the current active children to get disabled.

module.exports = MenuItem
```

Here is how I build my menu and its items:

```
<Menu>
    <MenuItem active={true} label="Menu 1"></MenuItem>
    <MenuItem label="Menu 2"></MenuItem>
    <MenuItem label="Menu 3"></MenuItem>
</Menu>
```

In the example, I manually generate "Menu 1 ... 3" but they would actually be generated dynamically.

I don't know if I got the right approach here. Maybe I should use Redux for this? Eventually, I should use `Routes`, because each MenuItem should have its own url (Angular-like, with `#menu-1`, for instance)

I also wonder what would be the best approach to give a **MenuItem** a content. Thanks for insight.

Answer (score 1):

This could be a candidate for [React.Children](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html#react.children), whereby you're able to specify `props` to be passed down to any abritrary child element - in this case `onClick`:

***Menu.jsx***

```
<div className="ui pointing menu">
{
      React.Children.map(this.props.children,
          function(child) {
              return React.cloneElement(child, {
                  onClick: this.onClick
              });
          }.bind(this)
      )
 }
</div>
```

But I might suggest an alternative approach, whereby you pass the list items to the `Menu` component itself, which can then render each list item individually, rather than just as `this.props.children`:

***Menu.jsx (Alt)***

```
render() {
    return (
        <div className="ui pointing menu">
          {
             this.props.menuItems.map((item, index) => (
                 <MenuItem item={item} onClick={(e) => this.onClick(e, item)} }/>
             )
          }
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: I thought about the alternative option already, but I was unsure about the content. Because each MenuItem should be somehow related to a content to display. Or it may be a link... And in this case change the uri path.

Comment: @Vadorequest Ah, I see - maybe passing the item along as a `child` would suffice? It's more of a `MenuItem` wrapper in that case: `<MenuItem onClick={(e) => this.onClick(e, item)} }>{item}</MenuItem>`

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend passing the `onClick` function as a prop of `MenuItem` from wherever you're rendering the `Menu`.

E.g.

menu_wrapper.js

```
// This is a functional component because it is 'dumb' - does not have state

React = require('react')
Menu = require('menu')
MenuItem = require('menu_item')

menuWrapper = (props)=>
  onMenuItemClick = (e)=>
    console.log(e)

  menuItems = ()=>
    props.list.map(function(item) {
      isActive = (item.label == props.activeItem)
      <MenuItem onClick={onMenuItemClick} active={isActive} label={item.label}/>
    }

  <div id="menu-wrapper">
    <Menu>
      {menuItems()}
    </Menu>
  </div>
```

menu.js

```
// Also a 'dumb' component - component without state

React = require('react')

Menu = (props)=>
  <div className="ui pointing menu">
    {props.children}
  </div>

module.exports = Menu
```

menu_item.js

```
React = require 'react'
classNames = require('classnames')

class MenuItem extends React.Component
  @propTypes =
      label: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired
      active: React.PropTypes.bool
      onClick: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired

  constructor: (props) ->
      super props

      @state =
          classes: classNames(
              'ui'
              'item'
              'active': this.props.active
          )

  render: ->
      <a className={@state.classes} onClick={@onClick}>
          { this.props.label }
      </a>

  onClick: (e)=>
      @props.onClick(e)
      console.log Object.assign @state.classes, {active: !@state.classes.active}
      @setState({classes: Object.assign @state.classes, {active: true}})
      console.log @state.classes # I need to notify the parent so it can notify the current active children to get disabled.

module.exports = MenuItem
```

Lastly, consider moving from CoffeeScript to ES6. Most everything you get in CoffeeScript is now available in ES6, and some. That said, I do miss implicit returns.

Comment: I don't like this approach, because you have the logic of the menu outside of its scope. It's not to the consumer to provide the logic of the menu, it's to the menu itself, otherwise it's not a right Component pattern.

Comment: Valid. The example you gave of logging the event can be done from the onClick of the `MenuItem` itself. If you really want an onClick passed in from the `Menu` then why not use event delegation?